# Developing multiple versions from one codebase

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, plugins

I have a MS Office plugin that our company relies on. Unfortunately, we have a variety of Office versions throughout the org, and we maintain three identical projects, named ex. Plugin2010, Plugin 2012, Plugin 2008. We use Visual Studio 2012 to develop in.

I would like to get rid of the duplicate projects and just have one that compiles against each version of Office's DLLs. I think it's possible, but most google searches that I've found about multiple version regard creating demo/ trial versions of commercial products.

How do I get started with this?

Comment: Is the code have any change for different version of dll ?

Comment: Yes, there's a different source DLL for each version of Office

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. My code is going to be 100% the same. No changes for any dll.